# SQL update set column = @ parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

doeas anyone knows how to update a table where column = @parameter WHERE SELECT

Basically I have a table with the following values. Table name is UserAttribute

```
ID|Name       |Properties|
17|Description|Student   |
17|Contact    |JohnDoe   |
18|Description|Worker    |
18|Contact    |MaryJane  |
```

I can update the fields with the following query:

```
UPDATE UserAttribute 
SET Properties = 'Charlie'
WHERE Name = 'Contact' AND ID = 17
```

For the results I need I would need a query something like:

```
UPDATE UserAttribute 
SET Properties = @parameter
WHERE Name = Contact AND ID = (SELECT HouseNo,ID FROM Table2 t1 
JOIN UserAttribute t2 ON t1.ID =t2.UserID
WHERE HouseNo = @HouseNo)
```

SQL doesnt allows the execution of such a query. Any suggestion on how to write the select statement in the WHERE clause?

Thank you!

EDIT 1:
Maybe the question is not the clearest, but its a bit hard to formulate a question when the problem I have is also hard to understand. Therefore I will try to write some kind of pseudo-code, hoping that it will make it a bit more clear.

```
UPDATE table
SET Column = 'value'
WHERE Column2 = value AND column 3 =(SELECT column from other tables)
```

Comment: the desired result is simply updating the row with the ID, the problem is that I need to do a subquery with a select statement in the WHERE clause, thats what I dont understand how to do

Comment: So how do you expect it to infer the `ID` you want to update is 17? Is there some logic that you haven't told us? Or are you trying to do it for all `Contact` rows?

Comment: well basically I pass 2 parameters, let's call the one used in this example '@'parameter, and the other one '@'HouseNo
so the query should be something like 'WHERE Name = Contact AND ID = (SELECT HouseNo,ID FROM Table2 t1
JOIN UserAttribute t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID WHERE HouseNo = '@'HouseNo)'

Comment: ID = (SELECT HouseNo,ID FROM Table2 t1 
JOIN UserAttribute t2 ON t1.ID =t2.UserID
WHERE HouseNo = @HouseNo) will error becasue you are selecting two fields and not one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but when you introduce two tables, you have to be consistent with the alias.  So
at the declaration of the update statement, you'd want to start with:

```
UPDATE ua1 
SET properties = 'Charlie'
```

Then create a from clause just as you would with a select statement, declaring your aliases:

```
FROM UserAttribute ua1 
    INNER JOIN UserAttribute ua2 
        ON ua2.UserID = ua1.id 
WHERE ua1.name = 'Contact';
```

Comment: It works like a charm :D Thank you so much for the help, too bad I can't up vote it more than once